# Hibernate Unable to create revision because of non-active transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

When I'm trying to save an entity using hibernate and envers, whilst the entity persists in database, the audit log is not and I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.envers.exception.AuditException: Unable to create revision because of non-active transaction
    at org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.BaseEnversEventListener.checkIfTransactionInProgress(BaseEnversEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl.onPostUpdate(EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.postUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:144)
    ... 96 more
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Every operation that Hibernate executes has to be inside a transaction. Do you start a transaction before the operation that throws the error. You have to show some code.

Comment: Just noticed that you're using Spring. Maybe if you just add `@Transactional` on the method that executes your hibernate code it will work. Note that `@Transactional` is usually used on the service/business layer of the application.